# Lightning: Save data to survive page refresh?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am unable to find any documentation or guidance on this, so I was hoping that either someone could point it out to me or guide me on this:

How do you save objects/data in Lightning so that it survives a page refresh?

I just tested out using HTML5's `localstorage`, and that appears to work.  However, without being able to find official docs on the subject, I worry about how long-term of a solution this is.

So, is using localStorage a safe method, or is there a different/better/Lightning way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning is meant to take advantage of JavaScript and mobile features, so using localStorage/sessionStorage would work well in most cases. While I haven't seen any documentation on this, this is exactly what I'd use if I wanted to make a page that could survive a page refresh. In fact, I did write a static JS library that I typically include on my Visualforce pages that cause the page to remember its state in the event of a failure, including governor limit type errors that result in a "white screen of death." You can just reload the page and your data will be safely restored.

Comment: Be mindful that localStorage is not inherently secure. If the data you're putting their is sensitive you may be introducing a security hole.

Comment: @Peter True. I'd prefer using sessionStorage, since that's the most likely scenario, a simple page crash causes a loss of work. View state should never be saved, plus inherently sensitive information, like tax identifiers, etc. My whitelist of things I automatically save in my JS library is intentionally restrictive to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you share static js library that you used for state saving in case of failure.